# Stuck on www.codeacademy.com syntax error unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I have been stuck on this problem on the codeacademy website (Javascript, chapter 4 section 8, rock paper scissors) for almost 3 weeks now, and I can't seem to figure out what it means.

Error message is SyntaxError: Unexpected token else:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var gameTimes = 0;
var computer = functions(); {
    gameTimes = gameTimes + 1;
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    console.log(gameTimes + ".Computer:" + computerChoice);
    return computerChoice;
}
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        console.log("Your choice: " + userChoice);
        console.log("The result is a tie!");
        userChoice = prompt("Please make the choice again!");
        compare(userChoice, computerChoice());
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    } else {
        return "scissors wins";
    }
    console.log("Your choice: " + userChoice);
    if (choice2 === "scissors")
        console.log("You win!");
    else
        console.log("Computer wins!");
};
else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    console.log("Your choice: " + userChoice);
    if (choice2 === "rock")
        console.log("You win!");
    else
        console.log("Computer wins!");
} else {
    console.log("Your choice: " + userChoice);
    console.log("The choice is invalid!");
    userChoice = prompt("Please enter valid choice again!");
    compare(userChoice, computerChoice());
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly, and you'll find your error.

Comment: Run it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and look at the indenting

Comment: Did you follow, and UNDERSTAND all the previous tutorials?

Comment: if you're this far and don't understand the syntax, you should probably start over

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't right. Take a look at

```
var computer = functions();{
```

should be

```
var computer = functions() {
```

and there is no `if` statement at the bottom before

```
else if(choice1 === "paper")
{
    console.log("Your choice: "+ userChoice);
    if(choice2 === "rock")
    console.log("You win!");
    else
    console.log("Computer wins!");
}
else
{
    console.log("Your choice: "+userChoice);
    console.log("The choice is invalid!");
    userChoice=prompt("Please enter valid choice again!");
    compare(userChoice,computerChoice());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple misplaced semicolons:

On line 3:

```
var computer = functions();{
```

Towards the end (probably the one giving the unexpected else token error):

```
};
    else if
```

Answer (score 0):

`var computer = functions();{` in line 3 should be `var computer = function(){`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `else if` has no `if` before it.

You can use `else` or `else if` only if it is prepended by a `if` statement.

Also, you've some syntax errors, which you should correct.